# Dynamic quarters using postgreSQL in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table as follow and want to create a dynamic quarters for this table

```
ID   Start_date    season

1     01/01/2022    1

1     01/01/2023   2
```

I want to divide each season into quarters till next season start

```
ID   Start_date    end_date       season    status.  status_level

1     01/01/2022    31/03/2022.    1          air      0
1     01/04/2022    31/06/2022.    1          lag      1
1     01/07/2022.   31/09/2022.    1          off      2
1    01/10/2022     31/12/2022     1          off      3
1    01/01/2023     31/03/2022.    2.         air      0
```

The first quarter of release call air and the next quarter after airing call lag and the all other quarters call off then when we reach to next season again it calculate 13 weeks periods from the start date until it reach to next season.

I have written this code but not working`

```
with
step1 as (
select
    ('2022-01-01'::DATE + (i * interval '3 month') )::date
from
    generate_series(0, 30, 1) i),
step2 as(
select
    date as start_date,
    cast(DATEADD(quarter, 1, start_date) as DATE) as end_date,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY end_date) = 1 THEN 'airing'
     when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY end_date) = 2 THEN 'lag_'
     ELSE 'off'
     END as status
from
    step1
)
select
    start_date,
     end_date
from
    step2
    where end_date < '2023-01-01'
;
```

`

Here is the error that I got it:

`ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`

Comment: Rather than generating this table through SQL (presumably using `generate_series()`, I find that it is easier to create these types of Calendar Tables in Microsoft excel. Then, export the spreadsheet as CSV and load it into Redshift. That way, you can use all of the formulas in Excel, which are much easier than writing complex SQL for such a requirement.

Comment: The problem is that for each id I have different start date i need to calculate everything on the fly @JohnRotenstein I also can write it in R / Python but I want to use Redshift and SQL because of heavy computation.

Comment: You could use `generate_series()`, but it only runs on a leader node, so it can't access the database.

Comment: could you please write the example because this one does not work `SELECT '2022-01-01'  + (i * interval '3 month') as start_dates 
FROM generate_series(1,50) i 
ORDER BY 1`; @JohnRotenstein

Comment: You could use `select ('2022-01-01'::date + generate_series(1, 50) * interval '3 month')::date`